# React componentClass on codecademy, what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React through Codecademy and it asks :

> On line 20, declare a new variable named Friend.
>
> Set Friend equal to a component class, made with React.createClass().
>
> Pass an object to React.createClass().
>
> Give this object one property. Make the property's name render.
>
> Make the property's value this function:
>
> `function () {`
>
> ```
>  `return (`
>    `<div>`
>    `</div>`
>  `);`
> ```
>
> `}`

my code is this:

```
React=require('react');
ReactDOM=require('react-dom');

var friends = [
  {
    title: "Yummmmmmm",
    src: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-monkeyweirdo.jpg"
  },
  {
    title: "Hey Guys!  Wait Up!",
    src: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-earnestfrog.jpg"
  },
  {
    title: "Yikes",
    src: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/React/react_photo-alpaca.jpg"
  }
];


var Friend=React.createClass({
   render: function(){
            return (
      <div>
        </div>);
   }

 });
```

I can't figure out where I'm wrong

Comment: I don't see where you are actually rendering this component (ReactDOM.render, that react-dom you are importing should work), you are not passing it friends, nor are you rendering it from the props you should be passing it. You need to render and pass it friends, somehting like `<Friend freinds={friends} />` when you render it, then used the passed prop `friends` to render it in that jsx.

Comment: I know but the codecademy checks every step to see if correct. The next steps will be to render the component probably.

Comment: I have no idea how strictly it validates your code, but I can say the spacing of the div's and return in the render function is really off. Maybe it lints that and doesn't like it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ridiculous error, React and ReactDOM should have the var keyword

> `var` React = require('react');
>   `var` ReactDOM = require ('react-dom');

Answer (score -1):

It seems ok. Maybe you have to put some spaces (`Friend = React...`, `function() {`) and better indentation so that their check validates correctly your code?